# Is there a way to apply the rules in .editorconfig in Visual Studio 2022 on the entire solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2022 for a `C#` project I am working on. I have created a `.editorconfig` file at the root of my solution where I defined all the rules I want to follow in my solution. Now, I am hoping for a way I can apply all these rules on the entire solution.

Using Code Cleanup profile, I can include fixers/rules which will be executed on the entire project. But, in my case, all the rules are in the `.editorconfig`. I don't know if there is a way to convert the rules in `.editorconfig` to fixers.

How can I force VS2022 to apply all the rules `.editorconfig` on my entire solution?

Comment: I have no idea what a fixer is, but you can use the updated `dotnet format` from .NET 6 and above to run against your solution and apply your .editorconfig settings to the entire solution in a post-build hook.

Comment: @DavidL Thank you so much! this is indeed what I needed `dotnet format ./SolutionName.sln --no-restore` is the complete command I executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is `dotnet format ./SolutionName.sln --no-restore`.

Here is the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-format) about the dotnet format.

Dotnet format is a code formatter that applies style preferences to a project or solution. Preferences will be read from an .editorconfig file, if present, otherwise a default set of preferences will be used. For more information, see the [EditorConfig documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files#editorconfig).